# get text from textbox and textarea and save in cookie value using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have one textbox and one textarea. I want to save the text whatever I entered in that textbox but that textbox is in Iframe.

How I do it using jquery or javascript?

Please help me.

Comment: Note that cookies can only hold 4K of data. Textareas are not limited in size, so this can lead to trouble.

Comment: Does the page with the textbox (which resides inside of an iframe) live on the same domain as the page which contains the iframe?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`jQuery.cookie`](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) plugin to work with cookies.

```
$("#myframe").contents().find('#textboxid').blur(function() {
   $.cookie('textboxvalue', $(this).val()); // for storing
});
```

Where `myframe` id of the frame and `textboxid` id of the textbox inside of iframe.

Comment: yes I have used it But without reloading the page how can I save whatever I entered in textbox in cookie value.?

Comment: as soon as I entered in some text in textbox i need to save in cookie.

Comment: Get value from the textbox (line 1 in sample) and store in cookie (line 2 in sample)

Answer (score 1):

[window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage) is another option working on IE8+, modern browsers without the 4K ceiling:

```
localStorage['textareaKey'] = $('#textarea').val();

$('#textarea').val(localStorage['textareakey']);
```

Comment: and in javascript is it possible to do this?